# C++ Template only if condition

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

So let's say I have a wrapper for arrays:

```
template <const size_t i,typename T>
class ArrayWrapper {
    T arr [i] = {0};
public:
    //constructors and operators like [] ...
    void operator=(ArrayWrapper<i,T> & arrIn){
            for (size_t k =0; k< i;k++){
                arr[k] = arrIn[k];
            }
        }
};
```

Now I want to be able to assign arrays to other arrays e.g:

```
ArrayWrapper<2> arr1({1,2,3});
ArrayWrapper<2> arr2() = arr1;
```

But now I want to additionally be able to assign shorter arrays to longer ones:

```
ArrayWrapper<3> arr1({1,2,3});
ArrayWrapper<4> arr2() = arr1;
```

here arr2 = {1,2,3,0}
but it makes no sense the other way round.

```
ArrayWrapper<3> arr1({1,2,3});
ArrayWrapper<2> arr2() = arr1;
```

As we lose information here 
So how do I tell the Compiler to not allow overloading this with j > i?

```
{...in ArrayWrapper class
    template <size_t j> 
        void operator=(ArrayWrapper<j,T> & arrIn){
                for (size_t k =0; k< j;k++){
                    arr[k] = arrIn[k];
                }
            }
...}
```

I tried this:

```
template <size_t std::enable_if< j<=i>::j>
void operator=(ArrayWrapper<j,T> & arrIn){
        for (size_t k =0; k< j;k++){
            arr[k] = arrIn[k];
        }
    }
```

But the compiler hates it ;(

Comment: What's the error message? You may want to use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: It's true that the C++ compiler really hates `<` and `>` characters specifying template parameters, due to the overloaded nature of those characters. You will need to figure out how to get the compiler to evaluate `j <= i` (in a boolean template parameter context) without using either `<` or `>`. I don't recall off the top of my head, is `std::less::operator()` constexpr? ... Or, you can always define your own `constexpr` helper function, and call it to evaluate the SFINAE operator value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `<=` should be fine. It's `>` that sometimes doesn't work in template arguments, but it can be fixed by surrounding the argument in `()`.

Comment: OP, you're using `enable_if` incorrectly. It should be `template <size_t i, typename = std::enable_if_t<j <= i>>` or something similar. Also, `ArrayWrapper<3>({1,2,3}) arr1;` should be `ArrayWrapper<3> arr1{1,2,3};`

Comment: – HolyBlackCat If I do:
template <size_t j, typename = std::enable_if_t<j <= i>>
the compiler says operator= not found for all asignments

Comment: -Matthieu Brucher
I would like to handle the arrays myself ;)

Comment: for me, `template <std::size_t j, typename = std::enable_if_t<j <= i>>` works perfectly but the code in your question isn't the code you're really compiling (there are too much problems: one for all: `arr[k] = arrIn[k]` doesn't works without defining a `operator[]()`; you have to write `arr[k] = arrIn.arr[k]`) so, please, prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: – max66 all these exist they are solely removed for readability
(//constructors and operators like [] ...)

Comment: I've supposed it; but your example is too much minimal. How can we say if your code doesn't works cause a part you've removed?

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a `static_assert` here.  Since `i` and `j` are known at compile time you can use

```
template <size_t j> 
void operator=(ArrayWrapper<j,T> & arrIn)
{
    static_assert(i >= j, "Assigning a larger ArrayWrapper to a smaller ArrayWrapper is not allowed");
    for (size_t k =0; k< j;k++){
        arr[k] = arrIn[k];
    }
}
```

And now not only will the code fail to compile but you get a really nice error message.

Comment: Thx this seems to be a good Idea!
I wonder if it is possible to go the other way though?

Comment: @mephphi73 what do you mean the other way?  Don't you only want to stop bigger arrays getting assigned to smaller ones?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714289/9238288) post about template casting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
template < const size_t i, typename T >
class ArrayWrapper {
public:
    T arr[i] = { 0 };
    ArrayWrapper<i,T>(){ }
    ArrayWrapper<i,T>(std::initializer_list<const size_t> arrIn) {
        std::copy(arrIn.begin(), arrIn.end(), arr);
    }
    void copyArr(T *arr, T *arrIn) {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            arr[k] = arrIn[k];
        }
    }
    void operator=(ArrayWrapper<i,T> & arrIn) {
        copyArr(arr, arrIn);
    }
    template < const size_t j, typename T >
    operator ArrayWrapper<j,T>() {
        ArrayWrapper<j,T> result;
        if (j < i) { 
            std::cout <<
            "Could not copy ArrayWrapper<" << i << ",T" << ">" 
                  << " into ArrayWrapper<" << j << ",T" << ">"
            << std::endl;
            return result;
        }
        copyArr(result.arr, arr);
        return result;
    }
    void print() {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            std::cout << arr[j] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    ArrayWrapper<3, int> arr1({ 1, 2, 3 });
    ArrayWrapper<4, int> arr2 = arr1;
    arr1.print();
    arr2.print();
    ArrayWrapper<4, int> arr3({ 1, 2, 3 });
    ArrayWrapper<3, int> arr4 = arr3;
    arr3.print();
    arr4.print();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer:

```
template <const size_t i,typename T>
class ArrayWrapper {
    T arr [i] = {0};
public:
    //constructors and operators like [] ...
    template <std::size_t j, typename = std::enable_if_t<j <= i>>
    void operator=(ArrayWrapper<i,T> & arrIn){
            for (size_t k =0; k< i;k++){
                arr[k] = arrIn[k];
            }
        }
};
```

THX to @HolyBlackCat!